# Can I use Magento to implement Telco services

Tags: products

I would like to know if I can use Magento to sell Telco services. I would also like to know if any companies have done this, and if there are any partners who could assist with how to go about this.

Thanks,  Amanda

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little too vague but yes, Magento can be configured to sell any services as long as you have someone who can code the necessary module or features for you.